# C++ Const-correctness with volatile and external data acess

Tags: c++, embedded, const-correctness

I'm an embedded C developer who has recently started messing with C++ code on an embedded device and am unsure about how const-correctness applies when a class accesses volatile data such as memory-mapped registers or data on an external device, such as an Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC).

For example, I have classes that interface to the device's hardware modules by accessing its memory-mapped registers through a pointer, like so:

```
class IOPin
{
public:
    /* Constructor, destructor, other methods...*/

    // should this be a const method?
    bool ReadIOState() {return portregs_->state;}

private:
    /* Other private stuff...*/

    // Constructor points this to the right set of memory-mapped registers
    volatile struct portregs_t
    {
        uint32_t control;
        uint32_t state;
        uint32_t someotherreg;
    } *portregs_;
};
```

The register names are of course made up for the sake of example.  I'm using a Microchip PIC32 device for anyone who's curious.

From my possibly incorrect understanding, marking a method `const` means that the observable state of the object should not change as far as the caller is concerned.  So should the `ReadIOState()` method *not* be `const` because it accesses `volatile` data that could change at any time and thus the caller would observe the change?  Or should it be `const` because the *method* isn't explicitly changing anything?

Currently, I am leaning towards not making that method `const` for the reason stated in the question.  This is especially true after stumbling upon [this GotW article](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/24/gotw-6a-const-correctness-part-1-3/), which states that the meaning of `const` is changing to mean "able to read concurrently".  My embedded application is single-threaded, but I suppose that could be a good litmus test for `const`ness in general.

Also, how does the compiler treat `const` methods?  That is, what happens when I want to poll the state of the IO like this:

```
// wait for IO pin to go high
while(!myIOpin.ReadIOState())
{}
```

If `ReadIOState()` is `const`, then can the compiler reuse the value returned after one call or is it smart enough to see that it is accessing `volatile` data and not do that?

Comment: I wonder if you can make volatile methods the same way you can make const methods.

Comment: void test() volatile {} compiles on VS2012 but I don't know what it means as I've never used volatile before.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, you can do it. It means that the function can be invoked on a `volatile` instance. Just like `const` functions can be invoked on `const` instances. You can even have all 4 overloads of a member function if you feel like it.

Comment: These comments made me realize that I'll have to think about how to use C++ objects in interrupt routines.  Variables used in them are generally declared volatile, though I'm not sure how that applies to objects whose methods I'm calling rather than accessing members directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just having pointer to the struct inside the class and you do not change the pointer, so the method can be const. The compiler should not reuse the value from the previous call, it is smart enough.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That is true and I keep having to remind myself that it's the pointer itself that being made const.  However, I think my question is a bit more on the philosophical side.  That is, does the use of const for a method imply anything about the return value of the method?  If the return value can change between two successive calls to a method even though the class wasn't the one who changed them, does it make sense to say that it is const?

Comment: Const is a keyword that is used at compile time only, at run time no special checks related to const are executed (only in case one has luck and const value is stored at read-only memory page by OS), this keyword only used to have more help (compilation errors) from compiler at compile time. Use of const for method does not imply anything about the return value of method. This is less intuitive side of C++.

Answer (score 0):

It should **not** be const.

Let's find a case where external state is accessed by C++ standard classes.

[system_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) is not const, nor is [steady_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now).

Reading the clock is pretty close to reading a register. In fact, steady_clock is sometimes implemented by reading a CPU register that contains the number of cycles since startup.

If C++ standard classes don't mark register-reading methods as `const`, your class should do the same.